# Bread + singular / plural pronoun

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, pronouns, nouns

I know that "bread" is an uncountable noun. So logically its referred pronoun should be singular as well, but recently, I have come across a sentence in a book (written by a non-native person), that had used "them" instead of "it" which sounds the correct pronoun to me. I was wondering which pronoun is the correct one?

> - Cover the bread with a damp cloth to prevent ...... from drying.

a. it 
b. them

Comment: This looks like a question in a test. If it is, (or even if it is not), what is your answer?

Comment: Not at all @Michael Harvey! As you know me for a long time, I always make my own examples up. As I mentioned within my thread, I think the answer is "it" here.

Comment: Why do you think that? Give a reason.

Comment: You will also come across **breads** in the plural, when people are talking about bread/s made from different ingredients or mixtures.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_breads

Comment: Well, @Michael Harvey, again, as I mentioned, while the work "bread" in an uncountable, I think a singular pronoun would fit better here.

Comment: Yes, bread, it, breads, them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"It" would be correct.  Though better would probably be:

> Cover the loaves [or rolls, or tortillas or buns etc. ] with a damp cloth to prevent them from drying.